# Appending an item at the end of listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am populating a listview from a database but in certain cases I want to add something to the end of the listview that would not be in the database, can I do that and if so how?

Comment: just a `SimpleCursorAdapter` nothing custom, it only displays a textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add something at the end of the listview that would not be in the database, use `ArrayAdapter` instead of `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Fetch all the data from cursor and set the data to `ArrayAdapter`. Add you external list item to adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add item to the source(list or whatever), call notifyDatasetChanged on adapter.

Answer (score 0):

getListView().addFooterView(myView) you'll need to do this before calling setAdapter.  Here is more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)